# Retrieving values from a large dictionary at runtime in a MacOS app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I come from a mostly ruby/js background. Our MacOS app hasn't been updated in a few years and there's no one on the team right now that does ObjC full time. I've always been curious, so I'm taking a crack at a ticket for a tiny feature in our MacOS app.

Here's what it boils down to:

We have a view with 5 columns, one of which displays an item's ID. We want to start displaying the facility name associated with that ID, which we currently have in a giant (~16k lines) json file.

Here's how the columns are initialized when we configure the UI:

```
NSTableColumn * checkedColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"active"];
[[checkedColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Active"];
[checkedColumn setWidth:30];
[checkedColumn setEditable:YES];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:checkedColumn];

NSTableColumn * idColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"id"];
[[idColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"ID"];
[idColumn setWidth:120];
[idColumn setEditable:NO];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:idColumn];

NSTableColumn * ownerColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"owner"];
[[ownerColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Owner"];
[ownerColumn setWidth:120];
[ownerColumn setEditable:NO];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:ownerColumn];

NSTableColumn * countColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"count"];
[[countColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Count"];
[countColumn setWidth:120];
[countColumn setEditable:NO];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:countColumn];

NSTableColumn * pendingColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"pending"];
[[pendingColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Pending"];
[pendingColumn setWidth:70];
[pendingColumn setEditable:NO];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:pendingColumn];
```

I added the following to create the new column:

```
NSTableColumn * facilityColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"facility"];
[[facilityColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Facility"];
[facilityColumn setWidth:120];
[facilityColumn setEditable:NO];
[inventoryTable addTableColumn:facilityColumn];
```

The original rendering in the tableView was this:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    IVClient * client = [allClients objectAtIndex:row];
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"id"]) {
        return PropToString(client.id);
    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"owner"]) {
        return PropToString(client.owner);
    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"count"]) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:client.count];
    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"pending"]) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithBool:client.pending];
    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"active"]) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithBool:client.active];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and i added a condition to match the new value:

```
else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"facility"]){
    return FacilityNameFromID(client.id);
}
```

I have only a surface level grasp of how to interact with Obj C data structures, but it seems like this should be pretty straightforward and i have to either:

1) Store the chunk of data in a dictionary and check for an ID match every time we render rows

or

2) Store it in a db and query by ID.

It seems like holding that much data in a dictionary is excessive but I'm going into this pretty blind. If I were in my comfort zone and building a backend for an api with these same specs, I'd definitely go the db route. I'm just not familiar with CoreData whatsoever.

Would #1 at least be realistic for a smaller dataset?

Answer (score 1):

16K lines, or even records, does not qualify as "giant" or even particularly large, in my eyes. A dictionary should be adequate. Certainly, it's where you should start before measuring and determining if the performance is a real problem. (Premature optimization and all that.)

After that, the first optimization I'd try would be to make a read-only property of `IVClient` called `facilityName` whose getter implementation does the lookup with caching. That is, something like:

```
- (NSString*) facilityName
{
    if (!_facilityName)
        _facilityName = FacilityNameFromID(self.id);
    return _facilityName;
}
```